# Why does a command with backslashes have different output between $() and ``(backticks)?

Tags: shell

I found this:

```
echo `echo \\n`
```

output is `n`

while

```
echo $(echo \\n)
```

output is `\n`

I knew $() can perform nesting while `` can't, but there seems to be other differences.

Comment: You might want to read https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03 for the standard's definition of command substitution, in particular its handling of backslashes. Roughly speaking, the backquoted form replaces the double backslash with a single backslash *before* the command inside backquotes is parsed and execute.

Comment: Backticks can be nested, they just need to be backslash-escaped. But that means backslashes have a special meaning inside backticks, so they need to be doubled to have their original non-special meaning.

Answer (score 0):

The backquote is used in the old-style command substitution, e.g.

```
foo=`command`
```

The

```
foo=$(command)
```

syntax is recommended instead. Backslash handling inside `$()` is less surprising, and `$()` is easier to nest. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

Comment: While all that is good advice, it doesn't explain why OP is seeing the behavior they're asking about.

Answer (score 0):

1. About `` `...` `` syntax
   In:

```bash
echo `echo \\n`
```

- `` `echo \\n` `` return `\n` text
- `echo \n` returns `n`

  - It's really different than `echo -e "\n"` who returns a ASCII LF character

2. About `$(...)` syntax
   In:

```bash
echo $(echo \\n)
```

- `` `echo \\n` `` return `\n` text but with `$(...)` returned like ONE token `"\n"`
- `echo "\n"` returns `\n`